# Is it possible to negotiate getting a better credit card tier without the annual fee?

Tags: credit-card

I was logging on to my online credit card account and I saw that there were now offering better cards but with annual fees. My current card is the same variation, but less benefits and zero annual fee.

I've heard some people negotiate their credit card annual fees and they are successful. Is it possible to do the same for a "credit card upgrade"?

I've been using their services for a year now and I've always paid my bills on time in full.

Answer (score 1):

It is sometimes possible to get the credit card fee waived for the first year.

But you have to be interested in the embellishments the card actually offers, not cost savings. If you are trying to pinch pennies while pretending to have elite perks, annual fee cards are not going to help you achieve that.